# Define an Entity with a Unique Key at the Model Level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Using asp.net 5 entity framework 7, I would like to define a field with a unique key constraint at the model level. I am not talking about a primary key.  I believe in EF 6 it used to be something like this:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UserName", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string UserName {get; set;}
```

Comment: please try with `[UniqueKey]` only

Comment: @tinka, there does not seem to be a UniqueKey attribute in EF7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure this in the `OnModelCreating` override. See http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/configuring.html#indexes

Example:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Index(b => b.Url)
            .Unique();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link.  It seems to me it would be simpler just to define it in the model itself but anyway...